# How to add a DialogFlow Agent as a Google Action?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In the Actions Console, I click on the Add Action Button and the browser sends me to the Dialog Flow Essentials page. There, I've created an agent what works. However, in the Actions Console, no action seems to be created.

How can I use my google home device to interact with the DialogFlow agent? Am I missing some step in the Actions Console UI?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the integrations window in dialog flow, click on the google assistant integration

[image: Integration window]

You will receive the above pop-up window where you can configure the action that will be triggered and if you want to make some changes to the integration you will need to click the manage assistant app option and the follow window will open.

[image: Google actions window]

Here, you can specify how the action will work and when you are done configuring it. You will be able to deploy it . You will need to introduce a few more things, so with this, your action will be totally personalizable.

[image: Deploy action]